# How to shrink tabItem size when more tabs are added (like google chrome tabs)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Currently I'm working on a project of mine. I'm using tabs which can be closed / opened( though they are not exactly same as chrome's). The tab item's data template has a label and a button. Here is my code.

```
<Grid Name="grid_test" Margin="0,73,0,0" >
        <TabControl Background="WhiteSmoke"  FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="12" Margin="0" Name="tabDynamic" ItemsSource="{Binding}" GotFocus="tabControl_GotFocus">

            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">

                                <Grid Name="Panel">
                                    <Border Name="Border" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent"
              BorderBrush="#999999" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0" >
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    Margin="7,2"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="White" />

                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#B3B3B3" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#F6F6F6" />
                                    </Trigger>



                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>




            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TabControl.Resources>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!--<TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem }, Path=Header}" />-->
                        <Label Width="100" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem }, Path=Header}" />

                        <Button Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="btnDelete" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}"
                        Style="{StaticResource btnCustom}" Height="12" Width="12"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>



            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

Now this is what is the case when my number of tabs are limited. Please see the image provided in the link
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TksoN.jpg)

And this is what is happening when I'm adding in more and more tabs. Please see the image provided in the link
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj6u5.jpg)

I've already checked out these links - [How to design tabs like Google Chrome tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643488/how-to-design-tabs-like-google-chrome-tabs) and [Tab control like Google Chrome tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213347/tab-control-like-google-chrome-tabs) , but they make no sense to me because I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to learn it properly. For now I only want to shrink the size of my tabItem when more of them are added. I would appreciate any kind of help.

**UPDATE:** I figured out the problem in my code and followed the suggestions of @Paparazzi and @Chris W. . My code is working fine but my actual problem is still not solved :(
I added some msdn code suggested by @Chris W. in the

```
<TabControl.Resources>
```

I added a viewbox in the required place. But, this code with viewbox shows a weird behaviour. When my first tab is loaded, it is filling up the whole screen. Size of the tabs are gradually decreasing(in all dimensions) with increasing amount of tabs.

```
<TabControl.Resources>
                <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
      Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
      Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                                <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                     <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                                                Grid.Row="0"
                                                Panel.ZIndex="1"
                                                Margin="0,0,4,-1"
                                                IsItemsHost="True"
                                                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                                                Background="Transparent" />
                                    </Viewbox>
                                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                                              Grid.Row="1"
                                              BorderThickness="1"
                                              Background="Transparent"
                                              CornerRadius="2"
                                              KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                                              KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                              KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2">

                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                          Margin="4"
                          ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>

               //...more code


            </TabControl.Resources>
```

B.t.w the solution suggested by @Paparazzi (i.e usage of scrollviewer from this post [Make TabControl Headers Scrollable in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764401/make-tabcontrol-headers-scrollable-in-wpf) )is working fine. This is the code inside TabControl.Resources

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
      <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="1"
               Margin="0,0,4,-1"
               IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
               Background="Transparent" />
  </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I'd probably have to see more of your stuff to tell whether you'd have anything in there to restrict it but if you were to apply [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871767/how-can-i-achieve-this-mix-of-stackpanel-and-uniformgrid-behavior/22871980#22871980) around an ItemsPresenter (your TabItems host panel) it should do what you're hoping pretty easily.

Comment: I'd try your answer. Thank you for that. Again, can I add only the tabItems to a viewbox, I mean viewbox should not contain, the content of the tab item, it should have only the tabitem(with header and button)?  B.t.w what do you actually want to see? It would be better if you try to be more specific, I'll post it if needed :) . B.t.w, I'm adding the tab items using the back end code.

Comment: Yea no worries. So if we look at a [default template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for `TabControl` we see a `TabPanel ` named `x:Name="HeaderPanel"` that has the property `IsItemsHost="True"` which act's as the parent panel for your tabs. If we made that our `ViewBox` then it would load whatever items you throw at it in there. There's several ways to accomplish the same effect it just depends on your layout goals.

Comment: I tried using viewbox in the dataTemplate section, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm checking your latest suggestion. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please tell me, how can I add viewbox to my code. For now I'm getting an error. I tried to add viewbox just inside my grid grid_test. So, for now I've my tabcontrol inside viewbox. But it is not working. And I've also added the TabPanel inside the grid( named Panel) section of my ControlPanel. I'm new to WPF, so I hope you understand :(

Comment: Inside my grid( named Panel), I even tried this one, but it's not working.
` <Viewbox>
    <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                       IsItemsHost="True"
                       KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                       Background="Transparent" />
     </Viewbox>`

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764401/make-tabcontrol-headers-scrollable-in-wpf pretty simple and it works for me

Comment: @Chris W. Hey Chris, your msdn code helped me get the job done. I actually put the "HeaderPanel" inside a viewbox. Thank you for helping me out. But I still need to test it with my code.

Comment: @Paparazzi : I already checked your link. But it didn't work for me. Actually my tab contents got shrinked when I applied that. I'm new to WPF, so I couldn't figure out the actual problem! I hope you understand. Thanks b.t.w

Comment: I've updated the post with what I tried, please do check it.

Comment: @ChrisW. : Viewbox is showing weird behaviour. The tabitem is capturing whole screen during loading. I've updated my post. You can see my code there. B.t.w thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @Paparazzi : Hey man your suggestion is working for me. Actually I misunderstood my code :v LOL . Thank you. But It would have been better if I could actually shrink it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the label in your tabItem dataTemplate has a fixed width of 100. Rather than fixing this width you could bind it to a property in your code-behind that held a count of the number of tab items (e.g. "TabItemCount"). This on its own is not useful because you obviously don't want a tab with a width of 1 and the more tabs you have the the bigger they would get which is the opposite of the behavior you probably want.

To solve this you would need a [converter](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/) which is a class that wpf bindings can use to take any input value/type and return another type/value.

The binding would then look something like this;

```
        <Window.Resources>
            <local:CountToWidthConverter x:Key="CountToWidthConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

...

  <Label Width="{Binding TabItemCount, Converter={StaticResource CountToWidthConverter}}" ...
```

The converter would look something like this;

```
public class CountToWidthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                 var tabCount = (int)value;
                 var tabWidth = 1000/tabCount;
                 return tabWidth;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {

                 ...

            }
    }
```

If the number of tabs is just 1, then the width of the label would be 1000, but as the number of tab items increased the width of each item would decrease. You could then set a maximum width for all tabs and then just divide that up among the tabs you create. The code in the converter class can obviously be made to do anything you like so you could handle all kinds of special cases. You can actually bind to any object type you like and it could be possible to make it work so long as there was some connection between the object you passed in and the required width of the tabs.

Converters are great for changing properties such as visibility, color etc where you want want the property value to change based on some condition such as making text turn red if it becomes negative.

Comment: Are you saying that the fixed size of the label is the actual problem? B.t.w thank you for the solution, I'm trying it :)

Comment: Hey man, I tried your stuff with my code. But I'm getting error in the xaml. In the xaml the `<local : .. />` is giving me error!

Comment: The column that you have the label set in has a column definition width of *, this means it will take the width of the objects it contains, your label is 100. If you want to know whether the label is the reason for the width then try changing the width to something else e.g. 50 to see if the tab width changes too. The the "local" is the namespace in which your converter can be found. It feels like you are trying to learn several things at once, this makes it hard to pick out problems. Try getting a converter working in a very simple example, then work up to your more complex case.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it :) . Yes, I'm trying to learn at lot at once. You got it right :) . I'd definitely keep your suggestion in my mind. B.t.w the example you provided in this link http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/ is also generating same error. I'm using .NET 4.0. Is it happening because of that?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? .Net 4.0 should be the problem unless you have several projects in your solution and they are using different versions of the framework (even then it is usually Ok)

Comment: `Error 1 :The tag 'YesNoToBooleanConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:WpfTutorialSamples.DataBinding'. Line 7 Position 10.`

`Error 2 : The type 'local:YesNoToBooleanConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. `

I made some edits. But still I'm getting these errors.Note : I've made no actual changes to the example. My project name is WpfTutorialSamples.DataBinding.

Comment: At the top of your xaml you should see a load of stuff that reads xmlns:.... you need to have one that reads xmlns:local="clr-WpfTutorialSamples"

Comment: Ok, I resolved all the error `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfUserControl;assembly="` I had to edit this a little bit ( WpfUserControl is my namespace for the project). But still my tabs are not shrinking. I'm trying to do it right, change few codes and stuff :)

Comment: Add this to window resources;   <local:YOURCONVERTERNAME x:Key="WhatEverYouLike"/>

Comment: Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Don't worry about errors now. I resolved all of them. Thank you by the way. I haven't tried INotifyPropertyChanged ( actually I'm trying to learn it). By the way, my tab size seems to expand but not shrink with more and more tabs. Maybe you can help me with this :)

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is where I would recommend starting. Once you bind some value in you xaml it will stay in step with the property it is bound to no matter where that property is changed. Can I suggest that if your post turns into a long list of comments like this then it might be worth asking a new question with a more specific theme (we've touched on many key concepts in this one post). I will be happy to help, as will many in the community, just remember to up-vote anything you genuinely find helpful.

Comment: Since I've low reputation, my vote is not working. Please don't mind. I'm trying INotifyPropertyChanged. I will post my code if it starts working.